# Java/Spring: How to Figure out MimeType on an InputStream Without Consuming It

Tags: java, spring, apache-tika

**BASICS**

This is a `Java 1.8` `Spring Boot 1.5` Application.

It currently uses `Apache Tika 1.22` to read Mime-Type information, but this can easily be changed.

**SUMMARY**

There is a mapper which User uses to download files. These files come from another `URL` separate from the application. The file may be a variety of types (`excel`, `PDF`, `text`, etc), and the application has no way of knowing what it will be until it pulls the file down.

**ISSUE**

In order to return the file download to User with the appropriate title, extension, and `ContentType`, the application uses `Apache Tika` to pull that information. Unfortunately, now that the header of the `InputStream` is consumed, when the application writes the `InputStream` to the `HttpServletResponse`, the file is incomplete.

This means that, in order to function currently, the application closes the first `InputStream` and then opens a second `InputStream` to return to User.

That's not good, because it means that the `URL` is being called twice, wasting system resources.

What is the proper way to have this function?

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```
    @GetMapping("/My/Download/")
    public void doDownload(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

            String externalFileURL = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";

            try {       
                InputStream firstStream = new URL(externalFileURL).openStream();        
                TikaConfig tikaConfig = new TikaConfig();
                MediaType mediaType = tikaConfig.getDetector().detect(TikaInputStream.get(firstStream), new Metadata());
                firstStream.close();

                InputStream secondStream = new URL(externalFileURL).openStream();   
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "DownloadMe." + mediaType.getSubtype()));
                httpServletResponse.setContentType(mediaType.getBaseType().toString());
                FileCopyUtils.copy(secondStream, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
                httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc of [`detect()`](https://tika.apache.org/1.12/api/org/apache/tika/detect/Detector.html#detect(java.io.InputStream,%20org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata)) says:

> The given stream is guaranteed to support the [`mark feature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true#markSupported()) and the detector is expected to [`mark`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true#mark(int)) the stream before reading any bytes from it, and to [`reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true#reset()) the stream before returning.

Javadoc of [`TikaInputStream`](https://tika.apache.org/1.12/api/org/apache/tika/io/TikaInputStream.html) says:

> The created TikaInputStream instance keeps track of the original resource used to create it, while behaving otherwise just like a normal, buffered [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true). A TikaInputStream instance is also guaranteed to support the [`mark(int)`](https://tika.apache.org/1.12/api/org/apache/tika/io/TikaInputStream.html#mark(int)) feature.

Which means you should use `TikaInputStream` to read the content, and try-with-resources to close it:

```
try (InputStream tikaStream = TikaInputStream.get(new URL(externalFileURL))) {
    TikaConfig tikaConfig = new TikaConfig();
    MediaType mediaType = tikaConfig.getDetector().detect(tikaStream, new Metadata());

    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "DownloadMe." + mediaType.getSubtype()));
    httpServletResponse.setContentType(mediaType.getBaseType().toString());
    FileCopyUtils.copy(tikaStream, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
    httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! However, this does not function. The error "java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported" is returned when using the example above, unfortunately. I'd appreciate your help if you have any other thoughts!

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Your answer works, HOWEVER, one must add another line making it a BUFFERED Input Stream. That is, InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(tikaStream); Then you use bufferedIn instead. Thanks! (Note: I marked this as correct, because it mostly is, but for the sake of future people out there, you might want to edit it to add the BufferedInputStream bit!)

Comment: So `TikaInputStream` is violating its own contract. You should report that to them. Try `InputStream tikaStream = new BufferedInputStream(TikaInputStream.get(new URL(externalFileURL)))`